# Could not connect to Restcomm IVR?

Tags: ivr, restcomm

I have simple restcomm IVR tree at http://54.249.98.150:8080/restcomm-rvd. Registered a  number as:93878460 at http://54.249.98.150:8080/restcomm-management/#/numbers/incoming and assigned my version of RVD to it. I have downloaded Linphone and tried to connect as sip:93878460@54.249.98.150:5080 but could not hear anything. However I saw some logs though at http://54.249.98.150:8080/restcomm-management/#/logs/calls. Could you please help connecting this tree for navigating the tree too. This is dockerized in AMI where necessary ports are open. -thanks.

Comment: Did you specify the VoiceRSS key as Docker image variable/parameter. This is needed for any Text To Speech (Say Verb) functionnality used by RestComm

Comment: Thanks jeand for this. I did not specify VoiceRSS key, sorry I did not know about it. Could you please suggest how to obtain and specify the VoiceRSS key in docker image? thanks.

Comment: well, I am trying getting from http://www.voicerss.org/personel/. and trying to add the key in a docker container. please advise me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks jeand for the hints. I did it.

Comment: Thanks. Feel free to upvote the answer.

Comment: Jeand, what i missed for Olympus webRTC call. I could not make it!! I don know I am not allowed to click up/down arrow button!!! to up-vote it.